# Slow video on Face recognition and detection

Tags: emgucv

I am using EMGUCV for face detection and recognition and the version used is '3.3.0' and IP camera used is CP Plus bullet camera.

I am able to do the detection and recognition but the live video on recognition is very slow , almost 10-15 seconds behind the actual stream. Not sure if it is anything with the code.

Below is the code i have done so far. Not sure how I can speed things up.

```
Form_Load()
{
    _videoCapture = new VideoCapture("rtsp://uname:pwd@19.18.1.40:554");
    Application.Idle += new EventHandler(FrameGrabber_Standard);
}
```

```
private void FrameGrabber_Standard(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Image<Bgr, Byte> currentFrame = _videoCapture.QueryFrame().ToImage<Bgr, Byte>().Resize(640, 480, Inter.Cubic);
                if (currentFrame != null)
                {
                    Image<Gray, byte> gray_frame = currentFrame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
                    List<Rectangle> listFaces = new List<Rectangle>();
                    detectfacensobj.DetectFaces(currentFrame, listFaces); //the actual face detection happens here
                    foreach (Rectangle face in listFaces)
                    {
                        faceResult = currentFrame.Convert<Bgr, byte>();
                        if (Eigenfaces.IsTrained)
                        {
                            Image<Gray, byte> grayFaceResult = faceResult.Convert<Gray, byte>();
                            var result = Eigenfaces.eigenFaceRecognizer.Predict(grayFaceResult.Resize(200, 200, Inter.Cubic));
                            if (result.Label != -1)
                            {
                                CvInvoke.PutText(currentFrame, Eigenfaces.eigenlabels[result.Label], new System.Drawing.Point(face.X - 2, face.Y - 2), FontFace.HersheyComplex, 1.0, new Bgr(Color.Orange).MCvScalar);
                            }

                        }

                        currentFrame.Draw(face, new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);
                    }
                    captureImageBox.Image = currentFrame.Bitmap;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

````````````````````
public bool DetectFaces(IInputArray image, List<Rectangle> listfaces)
        {
            bool isDetect = false;

            try
            {
                using (UMat grayImage = new UMat())
                {
                    CvInvoke.CvtColor(image, grayImage, ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);
                    CvInvoke.EqualizeHist(grayImage, grayImage);

                    Rectangle[] facesDetected = faceCascadeClass.DetectMultiScale(grayImage, 1.1, 3, new Size(20, 20));
                    if (facesDetected.Length == 0)
                    {
                        isDetect = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        isDetect = true;
                        listfaces.AddRange(facesDetected);
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Erro" + ex.Message);
            }
            return isDetect;
        }
```````````````````
````````````````````

Comment: How are you measuring the fact that you are so far behind? I don't see a frame counter. Are you running in Debug or Release mode? Are you compiling for x64, x86 or ANY_CPU? I would suggest x64 if you have a 64-bit OS. I would put some Stopwatches in strategic place to get some actual time measurements of how long things are taking. I would certainly emit a some kind of a trace statement to a log file or the console every time the event handler is called.

Comment: Do you have adequate memory, CPU and GPU, since I see you are using UMat's. We need some additional information before anyone can jump in and help.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I am looking at the live video i am showing on the app and thats how i am able to tell it  is slow...Also as you suggested it might also be the case i am running a debug/any_cpu build. I will run it in release / 64 build to see if there are any difference. I have a pretty good laptop , 16 GB ram .Nvidia K1100M gpu unit.